# Snapshot Azure database for fast revertion to snapshot

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have spent a considerable amount of effort creating a set of Azure SQL databases and importing data. Importing the data with the DMA tool took the best part of two days. This is on an 'SQL Server (logical server)'.

I now want to take a snapshot of these databases so that I can quickly return them to this initial state. I assume the best way to do this is to create a backup of each one that I can restore later. I'll probably want to do this restore quite often, so speed of restore is very important; 2 days is certainly unacceptable.

But I'm struggling to find out how to do this. There is no 'Backup Now' button in the Azure Portal that I can find. I've waited a day since creating the databases and still nothing is listed in the Available backups page on the Azure Portal. I looked at 'Configure policies' and this doesn't seem to allow creation of a backup on-demand, or to modify the retention period of an existing backup.

I'm probably barking up the wrong tree. What is the accepted way to create a snapshot of an Azure SQL database and then return to that snapshot quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server native backups are not available on Azure SQL. Here you have automated backups with a retention period of up to 35 days or you have [long-term backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure) that you can restore.

If you do not want to use long term backups, you can [export your databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) as bacpac to Azure BLOB storage and import that bacpac at any time you want. You can also export your database to a local on-premises storage.

Additionally you can create a [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy) of your databases, remove existing databases when you want, and rename the copy database as you wish.